# Dont know where the padding/margin comes from

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm working an a site and experiencing a weird issue with an image in a block element. When placing this image in a block, with all the padding and margins set to 0, there still as a space underneath the image. Here's the code:

```
<section class="page-block">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="http://navelpluisje.nl/theme/navelpluisje/images/ik.png"/>
    </div>
</section>


.page-block {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
}
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Navelpluisje/yTt2C/) overhere with the problem.

I've tested it on windows and osx on several browsers and they all have the same issue.

Does anyone know where this comes from?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the vertical-align top as demonstrated in the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt2C/3/).

```
img {
width: 200px;
background: white;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Truth be told, I found this answer with the following [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image). Which explains the following:

> By default, an image is rendered inline, like a letter.
>   It sits on the same line that a, b, c and d sit on.
>   There is space below that line for the descenders you find on letters like f, j, p and     q.
>   You can adjust the vertical-align of the image to position it elsewhere.

Comment: You got it! Glad I could help you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its caused by the default display property, inline,  of img tag. 
You can change it to block to get rid of that white space

```
img {
 display: block; 
}
```

[reference for inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below CSS Code:

CSS

img {
width: 201px;
background: white;
/* height: 100%; */
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```